# Mongoose Aggregate Field Results into Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm currently using the following code to sift through two separate collections. One collection holds a total list of messages sent to users. The second collection holds all responses that have come from users.

From the first collection, I'm building an array of messages sent -- then querying the second collection to search for all responses that don't have a match within that array.

Two questions:

1) Is there a better way of outputting Mongoose/MongoDB results into an array than the for loop approach I am using?

2) Is there a better way to compare these collections than I'm using?

```
// Find all responses (read) messages associated with a patient.
Response.find({patientID: patientID}, function(err, responses){

    // Store all msgIDs into an array.
    for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++){
        openedArray.push(responses[i].msgID);
    }

    // Find all messages associated with that same patient, but that were not included in the response list
    Message.find({patientList: patientID, msgID: { $ne: openedArray}}, function(err, unopenedMessages){

        // Store all msgIDs into an array.
        for (var j = 0; j < unopenedMessages.length; j++){
            unopenedArray.push(unopenedMessages[j].msgID);
        }

        // Output a list of unopened messages (msgIDs) and a count of total unread messages
        res.json({unread: unopenedArray, count: unopenedArray.length})
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.distinct()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) as well as maybe some usage of [`async.waterfall`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) to clean up the nesting a little:

```js
async.waterfall(
    [
        function(callback) {
            Response.distinct("msgID",{ "patientID": patientID },callback);
        },
        function(opened,callback) {
            Message.distinct(
                "msgID",
                {
                    "patientList": patientID,
                    "msgID": { "$nin": opened }
                },
                callback
            );
        }
    ],
    function(err,unopened) {
        // maybe handle error
        res.json({ "unopened": unopened, "count": unopened.length });
    }
);
```

Also you likely want [`$nin`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) for the comparison of the list returned against the field in the second collection.

The `waterfall` passes the result from each async call to the next stage, which means you don't need to nest each call within the other, so it looks a bit cleaner.

Comment: Thank for this the async.waterfall is a nice trick as well as the distinct. Appreciate it!